# Is it possible to assign a nice and ionice priority to all scripts executed by cron daemon?

Tags: linux, cron, debian-squeeze, nice, ionice

To be a bit more concrete:

I have a Debian Squeeze Linux machine with a web application that should become available all over the planet. Until now I had a bunch of resource consuming cronjobs each night (in Europe) without much impact on regional user experience. However now I cannot afford that the server gets slower at any time.

Is there a way to force all cron scripts  (cron.daily etc.) to inherit a nice and ionice priority?

Thanks for contributing!

Miguel

Answer (score 2):

Yes...

You could have the scripts source a particular set of environment variables or just run nice/ionice from within the script...

However, this is not a good resolution to your problem.

- Can you offset or stagger the scripts so that they're not contending for resources?
- Do you understand the timing or system activity patterns? E.g. *Between 02:00 and 04:00, there are very few users on the system, and it's a good time to run maintenance scripts.*
- Do you have enough resources on your server?
- `nice` and `ionice` aren't good long-term solutions. `ionice`, in fact doesn't have an effect on some of the more performance-based Linux kernel scheduling algorithms. It works with the [**CFQ scheduler**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFQ), but chances are that you want to use the [**deadline scheduler**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadline_scheduler) on a server system. That may have a bigger impact than trying to force nice/ionice on the processes.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to setting the crond service to run with nice and ionice already set.

[http://b.zekjur.net/2012/09/23/systemd-ionice.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20150423145758/http://b.zekjur.net/2012/09/23/systemd-ionice.html)

However, I haven't tested that one, so I can't vouch for it one way or another.

If that doesn't work, or if it doesn't help enough, you'll need to configure cgroups.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably best have these cron jobs run under a separate Linux user, which you can limit to lower priority.  Let's say you have such a user `batchuser`. In your `/etc/security/limits.conf`, you would want to add an entry for this user (-19 to 19, with 19 being the lowest priority):

```
batchuser    -       priority        19
```

Then any processes started by this user, whether from cron or not, will inherit this priority.  No modification to scripts, no env or profiles to set.

http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=limits.conf